# Laravel - Best Practice Update and Save Record to database using array of object

Tags: php, arrays, database, laravel, eloquent-relationship

I want to ask about best practice how you guys do when saving and updating data to database using array of object.

For example i have this AoJ:

```
[
    {
        package_id: 1, 
        posts: [
            {id: 1, post_id: "1d1479c6-c114-46d5-becd-e4715c14e57d", name: "Post 1", price: 3000}
            {id: 2, post_id: "84f37e37-d050-4efd-bd08-811ab893959f", name: "Post 2", price: 3000}
            {id: 3, post_id: "1d1479c6-c114-46d5-becd-e4715c14e57d", name: "post 3", price: 3000}
            {id: 4, post_id: "84f37e37-d050-4efd-bd08-811ab893959f", name: "post 4", price: 3000}
        ]
    }
];
```

For every array I will create a new row on database with new ID.

Here is what I want

How to update the data if i want to remove id 3?
What is the best practice to detect that some record should be removed from package?

For now my solution is:

```
[
    {
        package_id: 1, 
        posts: [
            {id: 1, post_id: "1d1479c6-c114-46d5-becd-e4715c14e57d", name: "Post 1", price: 3000, remove: false}
            {id: 2, post_id: "84f37e37-d050-4efd-bd08-811ab893959f", name: "Post 2", price: 3000, remove: false}
            {id: 3, post_id: "1d1479c6-c114-46d5-becd-e4715c14e57d", name: "post 3", price: 3000, remove: true}
            {id: 4, post_id: "84f37e37-d050-4efd-bd08-811ab893959f", name: "post 4", price: 3000, remove: false}
        ]
    }
];
```

So on updating package_id 1 posts when it see a `remove: true` it will remove it.

What do you guys think? Any suggestion to make it more simple?

NB: I can't use delete everything and post new one method. because every package_id posts has relationship to other table

Comment: In my view it is preference, It depends how the package is related to posts, if post may belong to many package and package are having multiple posts, it will be a many to many relationship, so I will create a pivot table or if a post can not belongs to many package, I would like to store package_id as foreign key in posts table.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu the first one is correct one. I didn't think about many to many. hmm interesting. thanks for the idea!

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu sure. it will be helpful if you can give a easy example for saving and updating on many to many. because my title about that. lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we discussed, let me post a basic solution to it.

We have one Post model like

```
class Post extends Model{}
```

another is Package model

```
class Package extends Model{}
```

if both have primary key 'id',

the pivot table describing many-to-many relationship between them will be

package_id, post_id combinly as a composite primary key, something like

```
Schema::create('package_post', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedInteger('package_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('post_id');

            $table->foreign('package_id')->references('id')->on('packages')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->primary(['package_id', 'post_id']);
        });
```

There may be some other columns, depending on requirement.

The relationship will be like

```
class Package extends Model { 

 public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany( Post::class, 'package_post', 'package_id', 'post_id');
    }
}
```

and

```
 class Post extends Model { 

     public function packages()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany( Package::class, 'package_post', 'post_id', 'package_id');
        }
    }
```

Now when you want to retrieve it or edit it or delete it, you can use attach, detach etc methods.

For retrieve, if package id = 1 and you want to retrieve all posts belongs to this package, you can just retrieve it like

```
$posts= Package::find(1)->posts;
```

For insert, you can use

```
$package->posts()->attach($post->id);
```

To update

```
$package->posts()->sync([$post_id]);
```

if you want to change post_id 1 to 2

```
$package->posts()->wherePivot('post_id', 1)->sync(2);
```

To detach

```
$package->posts()->detach($post_id);
```

To check if the relationship exists

```
$package->posts->contains($post_id)
```